# Multiple networks routing using docker compose and nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose

I am looking for an environment where I could host multiple websites on a single AWS EC2 host. So, I have an app where I have multiple components each as a docker which are part of docker compose. Each of the docker exposes a port, say componenta exposes 9443.

So, what I want is to deploy multiple copies of my app on the single EC2 host and route to them using nginx. so, there could be multiple copies of the components stack1_componenta, stack1_componentb, stack2_componenta, stack2_component2. So, the port 9443 exposed by stack1_componenta should be internal to stack1 only and should not be accessible to stack2.

Is there a way I can define a network to each docker compose and route the nginx to that network on the basis of domain?

Comment: See this project https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) describes the network setup you get out-of-the-box with Compose; each Compose project will get a separate Docker network `stack1_default`, `stack2_default`, _etc._  Then you need to write an Nginx setup that does host-based routing to those Compose files' published ports.  Is there a specific problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 0):

thanks guys for the comments and solutions. I was able to achieve this using the EXPOSE, network_type=bridge and nginx. So, with EXPOSE instead of PORTS, I will have those ports available only in the compose environment and I have opened the ports to outside of the compose using nginx.
Sample compose file for reference:

```
version: '3'
services:
  component1:
    build: ./component1
    image: <repo-url>/component1:${VER}
    expose:
      - <portnumber>
    volumes:
      - "<host-path>:<docker-path>"
    network_mode: bridge
    command: bash -c "while true; do sleep 1; done"

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    image: <repo-url>/nginx:${VER}
    depends_on:
      - "component1"
    links:
      - "component1:component1"
    ports:
      - 1443:443
    volumes:
      - ${BASEFOLDERPATH}/nginx/log/:/var/log/nginx/
    restart: on-failure
    network_mode: bridge
    command: bash -c "nginx; while true; do sleep 1; done"
```